# How to average columns over an ID?

Tags: awk

I have a large file of data with multiple ID's followed by several columns of observations. I need to average over one of the columns of ID's. I think this can be done using awk, but I'm not sure of how to set it up.

Data:
ID1 ID2 Observation

```
1 15_24 -0.00002649
2 15_24 0.00001584
3 15_24 -0.00003168
1 16_2 0.00002649
2 16_2 -0.00002014
3 16_2 -0.00003058
1 12_25 0.00009636
2 12_25 -0.00007514
3 12_25 0.00003021
```

Need the observations averaged over ID2 like this:

```
1 15_24 -0.00001411
2 16_2 -0.00000808
3 12_25 0.00001714
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe so:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=" " } { cnt[$2] += $3; lincnt[$2] +=1;  } END{i=1; for (x in cnt){print i++, x, (cnt[x] /lincnt[x] )  } }' file
```

Comment: Using associative arrays does not preserve ordering (not sure if it's relevant).

Comment: Order is not important, as long as the ID's stay associated with the observations.

Comment: My comment was meant to help/clarify, too. No need to take it personal.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. What if I have 40 columns of observations instead of just one? Can I alter this to average over all columns that are not ID's?

Comment: No need to set FS as that's the default, and you could use `++` instead of `+=1`. You might want to consider `sum` instead of `cnt` as the name of that array just for clarity.

Comment: You do not need to set `i=1`, use instead `++i` This way increment `i` before use, instead of after use. You can also remove some `{}` and `;`. So summing up you can use it like this `awk '{sum[$2]+=$3;cnt[$2]++} END {for (x in sum) print ++i,x,sum[x]/cnt[x]}' file`

Answer (score 2):

If ordering is relevant, this [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) script could help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk

lastItem==$2{
    observation+=$3
    observationCounter+=1
    next
}
observationCounter>0{
    print ++i" "lastItem" - "observation/observationCounter
}
{
    lastItem=$2
    observation=$3
    observationCounter=1
}
END{
    print ++i" "lastItem" - "observation/observationCounter
}
```